# Replace values in PyTorch tensor

Tags: python, pytorch

Given a `before` and `after` tensor, I want to replace all instance of `before` in another tensor `A` with `after` without using loops.

Example:

```py
before = torch.Tensor([2,4,5])
after  = torch.Tensor([20,40,50])
A = torch.Tensor([1,2,3,4,5,6])

result = replace(A, before, after)
```

The result should be `torch.Tensor([1,20,3,40,50,6])`.

Answer (score 0):

it's not the most efficient, but you could do something like:

```
In [37]: mask = (A.repeat( 3,1  ).t() == before).t().sum(0).to(torch.bool)

In [38]: torch.where(~mask, A, after[mask.to(torch.int).cumsum(0)-1] )
Out[38]: tensor([ 1, 20,  3, 40, 50,  6])
```

in this case you're materializing every possible value to check and summing over the matches to see if there is one. It's not a loop, so maybe can take advantage of the GPU, but it's not inherently better complexity.

What you really want for efficiency is a set operation, but I can't think of any in pytorch that would give you the indexing you're looking for. You could try to find some alternative using `torch.unique(... return_counts=True)` or search for other questions about intersection of pytorch tensors to see if there's a way to construct the mask more efficiently.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @nairbv. I get the high level idea. However,this code will not work for some cases like if `before = torch.Tensor([4,2,5])` and `after  = torch.Tensor([40,20,50])`, but that probably should not be hard to fix.